# Cutting copper sheets with a Dremel

Tags: metal-cutting, sheet-metal

I need to cut 0.2mm thick copper sheets. I do not want to use a nibbler or snips because I need to prevent the sheet from being bent as it is cut.

I want to use a [Dremel 2050-N/ 11JA Pen-type Rotary Tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077Y86FKJ) with a Rotational Speed: 5,000 - 22,000 rotations per min. and a diamond cutter, which has a diameter of 2.0 inches (50 mm).

Will this be able to cut 0.2mm thick copper sheets?

Comment: A nibbler specifically won't bend the sheet - that's the ***whole point*** of a nibbler rather than snips.

Comment: The foil you can cut with paper knife. To prevent bending put it on wooden or soft plastic surface.

Comment: Ecnerwal, a nibbler would do ugly things to material that thin and soft. Steel's another story.

Comment: Are you *sure* a 2” diamond cutter is made to be spun at 20,000 RPM?  Dremel provides abrasive cutting discs in their better/larger kits, but they're only about 1-1/4” diameter.

Answer (score 1):

A diamond cutter probably wouldn't do well. Soft metals tend to clog the abrasive material fairly quickly, resulting in overheating. Also, it's difficult to keep straight lines with such a small tool. If you're making short cuts it might be ok.

I agree with user263983 that a common utility knife is your best bet. Use a steel straightedge on a suitable surface.

Be aware that edges will be sharp. You may want to use a sanding block to ease them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your selection of tools will cut .2mm copper sheets but I don't think you'll get the results you want.

The diamond cutter will more than likely snag the sheets and getting a straight cut will be impossible without a fence or steel ruler. So if you get a fence, a sharp X-Acto knife would be my choice.